# regular expression: 'one or zero' does not work

Tags: regex

Test on this
http://tools.netshiftmedia.com/regexlibrary/

Well, I want to match the sentences below:

## first no me last

## first me last

## first no lo last

## first lo last

## first no te last

## first te last

## first no la last

## first la last

or

## first last

The regular pattern:

```
first ((no )?((lo)|(no)|(la)|(te)|(me)))? last
```

it can't match

```
first last
```

How can make this match with

```
first last
```

Comment: Is this valid too 'first no me last last last'?

Answer (score 3):

Add an optional space somewhere in the regex, eg:

```
first ((no )?(((lo)|(no)|(la)|(te)|(me)) ))?last
```

Your regex *requires* two space - one at each end of the optional central regex.

This regex moves the leading space of "last" to a trailing space of the "lo|no|la..." regex, giving it a similar effect to the optional "no ".

Comment: +1, but it might be better to write e.g. `first(?= [^ ]) ?` rather than simply `first ?`.

Comment: +1, please see my solution too, if you think that can work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression contains two spaces.

Remove one of them.

```
first((no )?((lo)|(no)|(la)|(te)|(me)))? last
```

or

```
first ((no )?((lo)|(no)|(la)|(te)|(me)))?last
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two spaces in your current regex. Make the second space optional.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex has one too many spaces...

`first ((no )?((lo)|(no)|(la)|(te)|(me)))? last`

if we remove the middle bit, we get

`first  last`

Note the space after first, and the space before last.  Remove one of the spaces and it'll work.

Comment: if removed the spaces, it doesn't match  "first no last"

Comment: You asked to make it match "first last", and my solution was intended to show you what the problem is.  You don't to remove all spaces everywhere.  You don't have to remove the middle in your regex.  You do need to do something to make sure that your regex matches only the stuff - spaces included - that you want it to match, and not require additional things that you don't want to match (like extraneous spaces).

Answer (score 0):

You only need the extra space if there's a `no`, so make it part of a group:

```
first ((no )?((lo)|(no)|(la)|(te)|(me) ))?last
```

Whatever you do with spaces, be consistent and be careful about what group they go in. Either put them immediately following a word they belong with or immediately before. This should be equivalent, but puts the space before the word instead of after:

```
first(( no)?( (lo)|(no)|(la)|(te)|(me)))? last
```

You might want to consider using the `\s` character class combined with `+` to be more flexible with whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Try this might help. I made this according to the link you provided, so could be wrong in the real scenario.

This will also *not* match (if you don't want) **first no la last last last**

```
first ((no )?((lo)|(no)|(la)|(te)|(me))? )?last$
```